# ValueError is preventing me from migrating in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm very new to Django and am primarily working through tutorials. I was attempting to create a model that has an author field. At a certain point when I was going through a migration process and used makemigrations, I received a series of messages in the console stating that I needed to set up default values for many of my fields in my models. So for author I put `default='someauthor'`.

I later removed these defaults, still confused as to why that happened. I then went through the 'makemigrations' again and those messages were no longer prompting me. I forget what I did to change that.

However when I try to migrate 'python manage.py migrate' I get this error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'someauthor'`

**I've removed all references to "default='someauthor'" but this error remains.** I will add that I have two models each of which make a reference to an author:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tutorial_posts')
```

and

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
```

I feel like that has caused the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ForeignKey field stores the id from the other table which is by default an `int`. If you add a default value as `string` it won't be able to convert it to int and provide you this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'someauthor'
```

You can check this yourself by trying this in a console:

```
In [3]: int('someauthor')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3c4d496afcf9> in <module>()
----> 1 int('someauthor')

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'someauthor'
```

What I suggest is that either you use an int value for default or set `null=True`:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts', null=True)
```

Comment: Okay, so even though I removed it, it still assumes the string is the default?

Comment: I think your migration files might have the value from the older model state. Please check that , delete those migrations and run `makemigrations` again.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'll try to figure out the process of removing tables from the database. So far it's not going well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and could not proceed with any other migrations

I was able to resolve by searching in the project directory for the string passed as the default value, in your case `'someauthor'`

You should be able to find in the migrations folder a .py migration file.

```
`
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('accounts', '0004_auto_20191221_2233'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='useraccount',
            name='username',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='useraccount',
            name='user',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default='string', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]`
```

Change the `default='string'` to `1`